# Suggest Jquery Preloader

Tags: jquery, html

Can you please suggest me some Jquery Preloader for my site.I want to preload a complete page i.e body of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just hide body block or even html block with display:none css property.

```
body { display: none }
```

And then show it with jQuery like this:

```
$(function(){ $("body").show() })
```

Adding noscript tag in head for users with disabled javascript.

```
<noscript>
<style><!-- body { display: block } --></style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: The screen is gonna be blank till the time the page loads.It will give a very bad impression.Worse then seeing images loading one by one.

Comment: If you need to show a progress bar while images are loading then use this (somebody already posted this, but deleted the post): [link](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/)

Comment: I saw you was getting an crossdomain xmlhttprequest error. You've probably tested this script local. Try it on some domain (like localhost or whatever.com). You should install IIS or Apache to make this script work on localhost.

Comment: thanks man.. can you please also tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: No problem. Here is the reason you want to know [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests)